# how to inject properties by java config for SpEL

Tags: java, spring, properties

i know that in xml config `<util:properties id="xxxProperties" location="classpath:xxx.properties" />` can inject properties that i could use in SpEL, such as `@Value("#{xxxProperties.item}")`  but how to use java config for that?